# 3D arrays in JAVA with different number of elements

Tags: java, arrays

how to make this kind of array (different number of elements in each parent array) if i want to take the number of elements from the user :

```
int[][][] test = {
            {
              {0, 0, 0}, 
              {0, 0, 0}
            }, 
            { 
              {0, 0, 0, 0}, 
              {0, 0, 0, 0}, 
              {0, 0, 0, 0}
            } 
        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is called a *jagged array*, an array whose elements are arrays of unequal lengths. You can prompt the user for inputs, then use those inputs to initialize your jagged array:

```
int size;
int myArray[][][];
Scanner s = new Scanner();

// Initialize outer array
System.out.println("How many elements in myArray?");
size = s.nextInt();
myArray = new int[size][][];

// Initialize each inner array
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
     System.out.println("How many elements in myArray[" + i + "]?");
     size = s.nextInt();
     myArray[i] = new int[size][];
     
     // For each inner array, initialize each inner inner array
     for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
          System.out.println("How many elements in myArray[" + i + "][" + j + "]?");
          size = s.nextInt();
          myArray[i][j] = new int[size];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're in luck. Java doesn't have 2D or 3D arrays, at all. It only has arrays-of-arrays. The snippet of code you pasted is merely syntax sugar at work.

Thus:

```
int[][] chessboard = new int[8][];
int row0 = new int[8];
chessboard[0] = row0;
```

An `int[][]` is simply a 1D array where each element in your array is, itself, an `int[]`. See, above, how we make a 1D int array and assign it to the `0` slot of the `chessboard` variable, thus proving `chessboard` is 1-dimensional just the same.

Forget about the syntax sugar and make the arrays as above, then you're in full control and can make each 'inner' array whatever size you want it to be. The only weirdness is how to initialize them. `new int[8][]` is the non-syntax sugar version: That makes a 1D array of int arrays with room for 8 `int[]`, and like all normal array initializes, starts out with 8 null pointers, entirely identical to e.g. `String[] x = new String[8]`, which makes no strings, and after that e.g. `x[0]` would be `null`.

You're then free to call `chessboard[0] = new int[8]`, etcetera.

Answer (score 0):

Java's two-dimensional arrays are array of arrays. When you create a two-dimensional array in Java, it is actually a collection of several one-dimensional arrays. For instance,
// read it as create eight 1-D arrays, each with a fixed size of four elements.
int[] [] array = new int[8][4]
// You could read it as creating eight 1-D arrays, each with an unspecified number of elements.
int[] [] array = new int[8][]

In the same way, 3-D arrays are made up of a collection of 2-D arrays.

```
// You can read it as 3-D array consisting of 2 rows of 2-D arrays with unspecified number of levels 
int[][][] array = new int[3][2][];
// Iterating through the 3-D array 
for (int[][] array2D: array) {
     for (int[] array1D: array2D) {
         for(int element: array1D) {
             System.out.println(element);
         }
     }
}
```